# Object null in other activity

Tags: android, bluetooth

Here is my main activity:

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity implements BluetoothSerialListener, BluetoothDeviceListDialog.OnDeviceSelectedListener {

          public static BluetoothSerial bluetoothSerial;

          public onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 [...]
                 bluetoothSerial = new BluetoothSerial(this, this);
                 bluetoothSerial.setup();
          }
```

And this is my other activity:

```
public class LaunchGame extends MainMenu {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 [...]
                 BluetoothSerial bluetoothTest = MainMenu.bluetoothSerial;
       }
```

The problem is when I want to make some stuff on bluetoothTest (second activity), the object is null and I need to keep the bluetooth configuration between the two activities...

How can I make this object persistent between them ?

Regards

Comment: *How can I make this object persistent between them ?* use service

Answer (score 0):

Make `BluetoothSerial` a singleton by using the Singleton Pattern. Make sure that `BluetoothSerial` is not holding onto context, views or other system resources. You can also make `BluetoothSerial` thread safe if needed.

Comment: Obviously you should not create singleton which contains references to Activity

Comment: Not so obvious if you are just starting to develop for Android. Lets not assume.

Comment: So, you are starting to develop ... in question we have `new BluetoothSerial(this, this);` where this is Activity (and we don't know what OP is doing with this references) ... so obviously it should not be singleton ... also singletons are bad in general